# Inline styling divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an application where I need to style a `div` as follows using javascript;

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "xxxxxxxxxx";
div.style.display = "block";
div.style.width = "100%";
div.style.height = "10%";
div.style.background = "#f2dede";
div.style.color = "black";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.padding = "20px";
div.style.top = "50%";
div.style.border = "5px solid #ebccd1";
//div.style.border-radius = "20px";
//div.style.text-align = "center";
//div.style.webkit-border-radius = "20px 0 0 20px";
//div.style.moz-border-radius = "20px 0 0 20px";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

[There's a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/ctb654of/3/)

The problem I am facing is that none of the commented lines above will work. As soon as I uncomment them the `div` won't show.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, an object member can't contain `-` in its name. 
You should replace this:

```
//div.style.border-radius = "20px";
//div.style.text-align = "center";
//div.style.webkit-border-radius = "20px 0 0 20px";
//div.style.moz-border-radius = "20px 0 0 20px";
```

with

```
div.style.borderRadius = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.style.webkitBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
div.style.mozBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
```

Answer (score 4):

You Need to change the code to

```
div.style.borderRadius = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.style.webkitBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
div.style.mozBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
```

Name of the properties are not same in the javascript as they are in css.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the casing of those properties to camelCase. '-' is an invalid character in JS variable names.

```
div.style.borderRadius = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
```

Answer (score 2):

Name of the CSS properties are different in JS.

```
div.style.borderRadius = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.style.webkitBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
div.style.mozBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/ctb654of/4/)

[HTML Element Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 1):

Used to this CamelCase as like this

```
div.style.borderRadius = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
```

Answer (score 1):

Working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4efg0uvp/) .Your code will be :

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "xxxxxxxxxx";
div.style.display = "block";
div.style.width = "100%";
div.style.height = "10%";
div.style.background = "#f2dede";
div.style.color = "black";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.padding = "20px";
div.style.top = "50%";
div.style.border = "5px solid #ebccd1";
div.style.borderRadius  = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.style.webkitBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
div.style.mozBorderRadius = "20px 0 0 20px";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```